# SQL Server 2008 Performance on nullable geography column with spatial index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, spatial

I'm seeing some strange performance issues on SQL Server 2008 with a nullable geography column with a spatial index. Each null value is stored as a root node within the spatial index.

E.g. A table with 5 000 000 addresses where 4 000 000 has a coordinate stored.
Every time I query the index I have to scan through every root node, meaning I have to scan through 1 000 001 level 0 nodes.  (1 root node for all the valid coordinates + 1M nulls)

I cannot find this mentioned in the documentation, and I cannot see why SQL allows this column to be nullable if the indexing is unable to handle it.

For now I have bypassed this by storing only the existing coordinates in a separate table, but I would like to know what is the best practice here?

EDIT: (case closed)
I got some help on the sql spatial msdn forum, and there is a blog post about this issue:
http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Be-careful-with-EMPTYNULL-values-and-spatial-indexes.aspx
Also the MSDN documentation does infact mention this, but in a very sneaky manner.

> NULL and empty instances are counted
>   at level 0 but will not impact
>   performance. Level 0 will have as many
>   cells as NULL and empty instances at
>   the base table. For **geography** indexes,
>   level 0 will have as many cells as
>   NULL and empty instances +1 cell,
>   because the query sample is counted as
>   1

Nowhere in the text is it promised that nulls does not affect performance for geography.
Only geometry is supposed to be unaffected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a follow-up note - this issue has been fixed in Sql Server Denali with the new AUTO_GRID indexes (which are now the default). NULL values will no longer be populated in the root index node.