# EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, sqlgeography

Long time listener, first time caller (finally made an account here!)...

I am using **Visual Studio 2013** with **.NET 4.5.1** and **Entity Framework 6** (final releases, not RC or beta).

When trying to add a DbGeography property to my entity, I get this error upon execution:

```
    One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
    Geocoder.DbGeography: : EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined.
    Define the key for this EntityType.
    DbGeographies: EntityType: EntitySet 'DbGeographies' is based on type 'DbGeography' that has no keys defined.
```

I have already confirmed I have no references to older versions of Entity Framework (discussed [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1535)). I have been using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409051/why-use-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type/7409237) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx) for examples/information as this is my first foray into spatial types in .NET (and SQL Server, for that matter).

Here is my entity:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; private set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string ZipCodePlus4 { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Geocode { get; set; }
    public Hours Hours { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; private set; }
    public virtual OfficeType OfficeType { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ProviderLocation> Providers { get; private set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your table DbGeography have a primarykey ?

Comment: @rene What do you mean? DbGeography is a built-in data type, as far as I know. In my SQL Server table, the column name is Geocode and the datatype is Geography.

Comment: Which namespace is the DbGeography in?

Comment: @rene In EF 6, it's in System.Data.Spatial, which is part of EntityFramework.dll.  It was moved from System.Data.Entity since EF 5, I think.  That's why I mentioned the fact I had confirmed there was no reference to an older EF version in my project.

Comment: Did you find [this workitem](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/650)? It turned out to be a namespace issue. From your code and comment I cannot determine if that workitem is applicable in your case.

Comment: @rene Yes, I had seen that one but it seemed like a duplicate of [this workitem](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1535), which implies that you must use System.Data.Spatial, and not System.Data.Entity.Spatial. However, as you'll see in my answer, I did the reverse and now it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This turned out to be the opposite of what I read from Microsoft's own response about a similar issue at Codeplex [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1535), and even their [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial(v=vs.110).aspx). Did I interpret it wrong? Both of those links indicate that in EF 6, the DbGeography datatype was moved from System.Data.Entity.Spatial to just System.Data.Spatial, but the reverse seems true.

I changed

```
using System.Data.Spatial;
```

to

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
```

and it works.

Comment: I ran into this same issue when trying to generate my DBContext. When doing this you also have to make sure to rebuild once the using change is made and BEFORE you generate the context.

Comment: That's Incredibruuuuuuuuuuu !

Comment: Wait that's not good.  That means that a core layer has to hang a dependency on Entity Framework, instead of just System.Data.Entity?  As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34211927/1507899

Comment: Yeah, good observation RJB, that's a problem.  I like to keep my domain model isolated with no references to data implementation specifics.  I literally had to add a reference to Entity Framework in my model, ugh.

I think it may be fixable with a clever data configuration map though, I'll be playing with it and will update if I run across any workable techniques.

Comment: Darn, looks like this is planned for a release after EF 7.0 is released, so stuck bringing database implementation into model for now. :(

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else whose might be facing this issue with EF6 (in 2021), try using `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeographyWellKnownValue` instead of `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography`.

This solved my issue.
(Not familiar with the intricate details though on how the error is resolved by this.)