# How to use spatial type with Entity Framework code-first without referencing Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geospatial, spatial

I have an entity with some spatial data... I am using `DbGeography` and `DbGeometry` referenced in the `System.Data.Entity` assembly...

I am not using that one referenced in `EntityFramework.dll` because I have a layered solution and I do not want to reference Entity Framework everywhere in my solution, but just inside the DAL...

When I try to add a new migration I get the following error:

> EntityType 'DbGeometry' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

So I tried to replace the `DbGeometry` property with a string `OnModelCreating` I have tried to write the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressInfo>()
    .Property(s => s.GeometryLocation)
    .HasColumnType("geometry");
```

But In this case I receive the error that the String data type is not compatible with the `DbGeometry` data type...

Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem? Does anyone know which data type is compatible with `DbGeometry` data type?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

[EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551142/entitytype-dbgeography-has-no-key-defined) does not solve my problem.. At the end, the author of the post says that

> [He] literally had to add a reference to Entity Framework in [his] model

This is exactly what I want to avoid...

Ryan also says that

> I think it may be fixable with a clever data configuration map though, I'll be playing with it and will update if I run across any workable techniques

Any idea how to fix it? 
Which could be a compatible data type to replace DbGeometry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551142/entitytype-dbgeography-has-no-key-defined)

Comment: When you reference the DAL then you have to reference EF as well if you want to use the DAL

Comment: @Sir Rufo: Everything is correctly encapsulated inside the DAL and with some other patterns I untied every other layer from EF

Comment: @moondaisy: I had already read that but it not solve my problem.. Infact Ryan says that he referenced EF in his model... But he says also that "I think it may be fixable with a clever data configuration map though, I'll be playing with it and will update if I run across any workable techniques"... I am looking for that solution

Comment: If you layer out your BLL also with business objects to then consume in the App layer, you can translate your Entities to those objects, hence only your BLL needs to know about EF. Problem arises when you pass your entities all the way up to the Application layer, instead... I'm in that trouble .... okok 1 year old post, I know

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EF5 you should use `DbGeography` and `DbGeometry` referenced in`System.Data.Spatial`.

But if you are using EF6 you should use `DbGeography` and `DbGeometry` referenced in`System.Data.Entity.Spatial`.

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.Spatial` namespace is inside `EntityFramework.dll`... If I use that, every layer would depende on Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

Somebody might come along and give an answer (and I really hope someone does), but as far as I know, this is just not possible. I have experienced with this myself for quite some time, and I haven't come up with a good, usable solution. You have to add a reference to EntityFramework.dll if you want to use DbGeography, no matter what (don't know about DbGeometry, though).

Here's the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.113).aspx

This states that it is in the EntityFramework.dll.

Comment: What a bad thing... All my solution will depend on Entity Framework :(