# Select data based on calculated distance between coordinates

Tags: sql-server-2008, coordinates

Database stores 4 points with coordinates like:

Name | Lat | Long

Point 1 | 11.111 | 22.222

Point 2 | 22.222 | 33.333

Point 3 | 44.444 | 55.555

Point 4 | 66.666 | 77.777

---

Technology:

MS SQL Server

---

Web application gets current user lat and long via HTML5, then it should calculate what points of those 4 are nearer then 0.5 km. **How?**

It should display Point 1 and Point 2 based on this illustration:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by nearer than 0.5km? Is it which the distance between two points are nearer than 0.5km?

Comment: @magnusw Yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Sql Server:

You can find ***distance between two coordinates in KiloMetres*** using the below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(@lat1 FLOAT, @lat2 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT, @lon2 FLOAT)
    RETURNS FLOAT 
    AS
    BEGIN

        RETURN ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371
    END
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
select [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](13.077085,80.262675,13.065701,80.258916)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22527076/730807)

### Using Entity Framework(dot net):

Entity framework 5.0 allows you to write LINQ expression like this

```
private Facility GetNearestFacilityToJobsite(DbGeography jobsite)
{   
    var q1 = from f in context.Facilities            
             let distance = f.Geocode.Distance(jobsite)
             where distance < 500 * 1609.344     
             orderby distance 
             select f;   
    return q1.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409237/730807)

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your point to the geography data type. Then you can do a WHERE @here.STDistance(testPoint) < 500.

The basics of using the geogrpahy point to calculate distance can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude).