# Using NULL with spatial indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, geospatial, spatial-index

I have a big number of photos (~10 millions) in a SQL Server database with geo coordinates column which can be NULL or NOT NULL (not placed or placed on map).

Also I created a spatial index on this geo info.

Now I am trying to select all photos inside certain polygon.

There are two ways of storing photos which are not on the map:

- If I assign NULL to geo location of all photos which are not on the map, performance of such query too slow (As I undestood, spatial index does not working with NULL columns at all).
- If I assign `POINT(0 0)` to geo location of all photos which are not on the map, performance is good, except of case with this zero point `POINT(0 0)`. Also such request returns wrong photos (they does not exist on map).

How can I overcome these problems?

Should I add column which would contains a bit for NULL or NOT NULL and create index from two columns (this column and geo info)?

**UPDATE** I tried to create index from two columns, but it is impossible, because spatial index contains only one column with geo info ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb934196.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand there are two solution of my problem:

- Moving of zero point `POINT(0 0)` to far north point `POINT(0 90)`. This solution is not ideal, but working and does not require change of SQL Server version.
- Changing SQL Server version to 110 (in this version bug with NULL is fixed) by executing of this script:
  ALTER DATABASE database_name 
  SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Answer (score 3):

What version of SQL server are you using?
There is a know issue with nullable spatial columns in 2008 and 2008 R2
Please look at my question on this same topic: [SQL Server 2008 Performance on nullable geography column with spatial index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954875/sql-server-2008-performance-on-nullable-geography-column-with-spatial-index)

I solved this issue by having a separate table to store the spatial datatype.
In my project I hava a Address table with an Id column, a Latitude and a Longitude Column
Then I have a AddressCoordinate table that has a foreign key constraint on the Id of Address, and a Geography column.
Finally I have a script to populate missing valid AddressCoordinates on a nighly basis.

Comment: I agree that it is not an ideal solution, but it does have it's upsides:
1: No dummy data inserted that needs to be filtered out later.
2: Size and performance: Dummy data will also significantly increase the index size, and thus can influence the execution time.
3: I only had the spatial data type stored on that table, so the only duplication was of the PK. 
This trade off made it worth my while, but I understand you came to a different conclusion for your case.